# comparing lines with a reverse order of objects by perl

Tags: perl

I'm pretty new in using Perl and I need to use it to compare all the lines of a file. The file has two IDs separated by | and a value for each ID pair. It looks like this:

```
a|b 9
a|a 1
a|c 4
s|c 3
f|e NA
a|d 2
d|a 2
d|b 5
c|l NA
c|s 3
```

I would like to eliminate a row if there is another with the same IDs (letters), but in an inverted order (like a|d and d|a), the rows in which I have "NA" as value and the rows with the same ID in both positions (like a|a 1).
From the example here, I would like to obtain an output like this:

```
a|b 9
a|c 4
s|c 3
a|d 2
d|b 5
```

I'm trying a code that I wrote. It is able to eliminate the rows with "NA" and the rows in which the IDs are the same (like a|a 1), but it is not able to detect the rows with the inverted IDs.

```
$file = "test.txt";
open (HAN, "$file") || die "No input file";
@r = <HAN>;
close (HAN);
for ($i=0; $i<=$#r; $i++) {
    chomp($r[$i]);      
    ($id, $v) = split (/\t/, $r[$i]);
    if ( $v ne NA ) {
       ($id1, $id2) = split (/\|/, $id);            
        $ii = $id1."|".$id2;
        $dd = $id2."|".$id1;
        if(($id1 ne $id2)||($ii ne $dd)){
           print "$id\t$v\n";
        }
    }       
}
```

Any help is absolutely welcome!

Thank you in advance,
Gab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just another approach, in case the previous 2 responses confuse you:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %previous;
open (my $IN,'<','file.txt') or die "$!";
while (<$IN>) {
    my ($tmp,$v)=split/ /;
    next if $v=~/NA/; #remove the rows in which I have "NA" as value 
    my ($id1,$id2)=split/\|/,$tmp;
    next if $id1 eq $id2; #remove the rows with the same ID in both positions
    next if exists $previous{"$id2|$id1"}; #remove the row if there is another with the same IDs (letters), but in an inverted order
    $previous{$tmp}=1;
    print;
}
close $IN;
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem, you need to keep track of all the pairs (of IDs) encountered so far. When ever a new line is processed, it needs to be matched with the list of ID pairs to find if it is an inverted pair.

The following modifications make it work:

```
$file = "test.txt";
open (HAN, "$file") || die "No input file";
@r = <HAN>;
@encountered;
close (HAN);
for ($i=0; $i<=$#r; $i++) {
    chomp($r[$i]);
    $present=0;
    $invertPr=0;
    ($id, $v) = split (/\t/, $r[$i]);
    if ( $v ne NA ) {
       ($id1, $id2) = split (/\|/, $id);
        if($id1 eq $id2) {
            next;
        }
        for($j = 0; $j < $#encountered; $j+=2) {
            if($encountered[$j] eq $id1 && $encountered[$j+1] eq $id2) {
                $present = 1;
            }
            if($encountered[$j+1] eq $id1 && $encountered[$j] eq $id2) {
                $invertPr = 1;
            }
        }
        if($present == 0) {
           push(@encountered, $id1);
           push(@encountered, $id2);
        }
        if($invertPr == 0) {
           print "$id\t$v\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following script always uses the 'lower' id as the first part of the key. Therefore, you do not have to care about inverted ids:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

sub compare {
    my %result;
    for (@_) {
        my ($id1, $id2, $value) = /(.+)\|(.+) (.+)/;
        next if $id1 eq $id2 or 'NA' eq $value;
        ($id1, $id2) = sort $id1, $id2;
        next if exists $result{"$id1|$id2"};
        $result{"$id1|$id2"} = $value;
    }
    return join "\n", map "$_ $result{$_}", keys %result;
}

print compare(<DATA>);

__DATA__
a|b 9
a|a 1
a|c 4
s|c 3
f|e NA
a|d 2
d|a 2
d|b 5
c|l NA
c|s 3
```

Comment: @Gabelins: Sorry, simplified.